# Show that a semigroup is strongly continuous on the domain of its generator

Tags: functional-analysis, semigroup-of-operators

Let $(\kappa_t)_{t\ge0}$ be a semigroup of linear, conservative, contractive and nonnegative operators on $C_0(E)$ with $$(\kappa_tf)(x)\xrightarrow{t\to0}f(x)\tag1\;\;\;\text{for all }x\in\mathbb R$$ for all $f\in C_0(\mathbb R)$. Let $(\mathcal D(A),A)$ denote the generator of $(\kappa_t)_{t\ge0}$. Suppose we know that $$\kappa_tf-f=\int_0^t\kappa_s Af\:{\rm d}s\;\;\;\text{for all }f\in\mathcal D(A)\tag2.$$

> How can we conclude that $(\kappa_t)_{t\ge0}$ is strongly continuous on $\mathcal D(A)$?

Clearly, $(2)$ again yields $(1)$, but I don't see why the convergence is uniform with respect to $x$.

Comment: $C_{0}(\mathbb{R})$ denotes the space of continuous functions vanishing at infinity, right?

Comment: @sharpe Yes, that's correct.

Comment: $(2)$ gives $$\|\kappa_t f-f\|_{\infty} \leq t \|Af\|_{\infty}$$ which immediately yields the desired convergence.

Comment: @saz Is it possible to obtain the strong continuity without $(2)$? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3096864/how-can-we-prove-that-a-locally-bounded-semigroup-is-strongly-continuous-on-th